# Minimalising/Optimising Repetitious Code

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Here is my code to "animate" the `TPanel` when the mouse cursor is hovered over it. I also have a code block to unanimate it.

```
procedure Tmain.pStarting1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if sender = pStarting1 then pStarting1.BevelInner := bvLowered;
  if sender = pStarting2 then pStarting2.BevelInner := bvLowered;
  if sender = pStarting3 then pStarting3.BevelInner := bvLowered;
  if sender = pStarting4 then pStarting4.BevelInner := bvLowered;
  if sender = pStarting5 then pStarting5.BevelInner := bvLowered;
  if sender = pStarting6 then pStarting6.BevelInner := bvLowered;
  if sender = pStarting7 then pStarting7.BevelInner := bvLowered;
  if sender = pStarting8 then pStarting8.BevelInner := bvLowered;
  if sender = pStarting9 then pStarting9.BevelInner := bvLowered;
end;
```

As you can see, its very repetitious and since I have another 27 `TPanel`s to animate, that would mean another 27 lines of repetitious code. So is there a way I can optimise this?

I have also tried placing that block of code into a separate procedure (in the same unit). but Delphi tells me that `sender` is undeclared.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if Sender is TPanel then
  TPanel(Sender).BevelInner := bvLowered;
```

or, if you are certain that `Sender` is always a `TPanel`, simply

```
(Sender as TPanel).BevelInner := bvLowered;
```

or (if you are *really* certain)

```
TPanel(Sender).BevelInner := bvLowered;
```

Comment: @Blobby: You and David are not from the same planet! ;)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You just can't please everyone at the same time can you!!  ;-)

Comment: What if the sender is one object, but I want to change the property of another object? I've tried:

`if Sender is TImage then TPanel(Sender).BevelInner := bvLowered` so far.

Comment: @petersmileyface: That won't work. If `Sender` is a `TImage`, then it has no `BevelInner` property. It's like saying "if the patient is a man, then remove his ovaries."

Comment: About the first example: after successful `Sender is TPanel` it's safe to typecast directly: `TPanel(Sender)`, no need for `Sender as TPanel`

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I am not sure what you mean by not been on the same planet as David :) In any case I voted for `TPanel(Sender).BevelInner := bvLowered;` because I do the same with actions eg, `TAction(Sender).Enabled := True` etc

Comment: @TOndrej: I know, but I think it looks neater with `as`. It is in 'harmony' with the `is` from the preceding  line.

Comment: @Andreas, but using `as` after the `is` is inefficient, as `as` tests for type before doing the exact same cast you'd do yourself. So `is` tests for type, and then `as` tests for type and raises an exception if it's not that type. It's more efficient to use `if Sender is TSomething then TSomething(Sender)` than doing the type test twice and setting up an exception stack for the second one.  :)

Comment: The issue of efficiency is generally completely irrelevant here. It's a UI event handler. You can't measure the difference between any of the options. So stop worrying about pointless things and write code that is clean. You have two options. If you there is a possibility that `Sender` may not be `TPanel` then use `is` followed by the unchecked cast. If you are sure that `Sender` will always be `TPanel` then use just the checked `as` cast so that you get runtime errors in case your static analysis was incorrect.

Comment: @TLama, the exception is there by design (and makes sense). It's the purpose of using `as` - you try to use something `as` something else, and get an exception if you can't. The way around it is to use `is` and a direct cast: `if ThisThing is ThatThing then ThatThing(ThisThing).SomePropOrMethod;` = no exception. `with (ThisThing as ThatThing) do SomePropOrMethod;` = miscatch protection with exception.

Comment: @David, I'm so glad you can generalize everyone's code as not needing optimization at any point ever. :) In the case of the original code sample, where the event handler can be called by 36 different panels (possibly repeatedly), how can you say with certainty that optimization is irrelevant? Not saying you're necessarily wrong, but perhaps you should offer more of an opinion instead of a directive. :-) And I personally believe in only assigning the event handler to the same type of components, naming it appropriately, and directly typecasting `Sender` to the proper type. :)

Comment: @Ken The mouse can only enter one panel at a time. Opinions don't really come into it. Unless you are running on a 30 year old computer.

Comment: @David, you missed my point entirely (in my original comment). What I said was that using both `is` and `as` was unnecessary as well as inefficient (regardless of how much). I thought 'unnecessary", regardless of efficiency, was pretty self-explanatory. I see we're in another hyper-critical mood today. I'll choose my words and phrasing very carefully. ;-)

Comment: @Ken Absolutely no point using both `is` and `as`. Don't think I said that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fourth way, by taking advantage of the [`absolute`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables#Absolute_Addresses) keyword.

```
procedure Tmain.pStarting1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
var
    Panel: TPanel absolute Sender;

begin
    if Sender is TPanel then
        Panel.BevelInner := bvLowered;
end;
```